# Transform individual letters while keeping non-breaking spaces

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a centered text with non-breaking spaces, for instance:

```
<p>Never break these&nbsp;two or these&nbsp;two</p>
```

I'd like to transform individual letters while keeping the non-breaking behaviour. I tried adding a span around the letters to transform like so:

```
<p>Never break these&nbsp;two or <span>t</span>hese&nbsp;two</p>

span { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

But unfortunately because I make the spans `inline-block` for the transform to work, this creates undesirable breaks.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/hd84cvpf/

[image]

Any clue on how to get the desired behaviour, which would be like without the `span`, but with a rotated letter?

## Update:

The [solution of delinear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889597/1951907) seems correct, but not properly supported by Chrome (62.0.3202.62) when several letters are styled this way. In most cases, Chrome succeeds to provide the proper breaking behaviour, but sometimes it fails, see https://jsfiddle.net/htq2eqnk/2/ (try resizing the window):

[image]

Firefox always breaks properly.

## Workaround:

My current workaround is to manually break using `<br />` elements exactly where desired, which I can disable using `display:none` for larger screen sizes based on media queries. It's a little ugly and not generic, but it works for short but important text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see to achieve this is to add a wrapper around the elements you don't want to break with a `white-space: nowrap` style applied.

```
<p>Never break these&nbsp;two or <span class="wrapper"><span class="inner">t</span>hese&nbsp;two</span></p>

span.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

span.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/htq2eqnk/)

Comment: Sweet. For some reason, among all the things I tried, I did try something similar on my production example but it didn't work either... I'll see what went wrong and come back to accept your answer or refine my question.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue I was having: it's mostly Chrome not doing the right thing (see my update). I accepted your answer as I think it's the correct solution, though it's not correctly supported by Chrome. If you have a workaround for Chrome, I'd gladly take it ;)